# Possible to add an event listener to a control that contains (potentially) infinite events?

Tags: c#, event-listener

Is there such a thing as an event listener that can attach itself to a `Control` (or other) and pickup any events that are fired by Child Controls inside that parent control?

Doubtful, but worth a try asking as I couldnt find anything from google!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Child controls have a reference to their parent, and the parent usually keeps references to the child controls (done automatically by VS's designer), but other than that, they don't touch each other's events.